# How to pass value through UIColorFromRGB in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

In this code coloring returning value =0X90EE90

```
  coloring=[colorall objectForKey:globallinecolor];

     shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColorFromRGB(coloring).CGColor;
```

but this code give me error, could anyone help how could I pass the value through UIColorFromRGB.

Comment: What is the type of `coloring`, what is the error ? Also, look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563552/hex-to-uicolorfromrgb.

Comment: what you got as error?

Comment: coloring is (NSString *coloring=[[NSString alloc]init];)
errr: invalid operands to binary expression ('NSString *' and 'int')

Comment: @Ron can you post the value of NSString object? Thanks

Comment: value is 0X90EE90 which is a colorcode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are retrieving a NSString object (*coloring*) but the macro expects an integer.

To get an integer from a hex string you can use **NSScanner** class.

Along the lines of:

```
unsigned int hexValue = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:coloring];
[scanner setScanLocation:0]; // depends on your exact string format you may have to use location 1
[scanner scanHexInt:&hexValue];

shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColorFromRGB(hexValue).CGColor;
```

Comment: I have tried this  but if I do NSLog of [coloring integerValue] it returns 0

Answer (score 11):

**Create a method macro like:**

```
  #define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

**and use as:**

```
 self.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0X90EE90);
```

Though the OP asked in `ObjC`, someone may come here in search of `Swift`:

```
func UIColorFromHex(rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

**and use as:**

```
let someColor = UIColorFromHex(0x27a9e0)
```

Comment: I have already done those but instad of (0XFFFFFF) i need to put dynamic value there which I am getting from coloring=[colorall objectForKey:globallinecolor];

Comment: what is data type of `coloring`?

Comment: coloring is (NSString *coloring=[[NSString alloc]init];) errr: invalid operands to binary expression ('NSString *' and 'int')

Comment: you need to convert string to hex.  have a look at answer of `Prasanna Gupta` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056757/how-to-convert-an-nsstring-to-hex-values

Comment: @preetam - Doesn't need to be converted to hex, but does need to be a number, not a string.  Using `integerValue` should work.  (Well, maybe not on hex -- convert the hex to decimal before storing in the string.)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, I found this solutions online (can't find it now) which is near what someone else has put here but may help.

Try this,

```
coloring=[colorall objectForKey:globallinecolor];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColorFromRGB(colourFromHexString:coloring).CGColor;
```

And then

```
-(UIColor *)colourFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString
{
    unsigned rgbValue = 0;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
    [scanner setScanLocation:2]; // bypass '#' character
    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];
   return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just save the hexadecimal value as an Integer like so:         
`[defaults setInteger:0x640800 forKey:@"in"];`

And then do something like this:

```
defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
long rgbCode = [defaults integerForKey:packageName];
_languageButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(rgbCode);
```